# jQuery Animation function is not working in my jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery and web development.
I have some problem with animate function of jquery.
I have also created a fiddle here:-
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Updatebaba/4zcutrpn/4/)
And here is the main function of the script:-
I have not added the full script as it may be a problem with css as i am a beginner

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var showImage=function(photoObject,direction,maincontainer){
    alert("I am Also Called");
    animating=true;
    if(direction=="next"){
        maincontainer.animate({"left":"1080px"},slideshowspeed,linear,function(){
        alert("I am also called");
        $("#slider_caption").css({
        "background-image" : "photoObject.image"
        });
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: One mistake I see is that `linear` should be **string**, otherwise `undefined` will be used.

Comment: on correcting it still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of syntax errors:

1. Incorrect closing of `}`
2. Not checking if `maincontainer` exists or not.

```js
var slideshowspeed=6000;
//variable to store the images we need to set as background
//which also includes some text and url's.
//speed of the automatic slideshow
var photos = [
  {
    "title" : "Stairs",
    "image" : "image1.jpg",

    "firstline" : "Going on",
    "secondline" : "vacation?"
  }, {
    "title" : "Office Appartments",
    "image" : "image2.jpg",

    "firstline" : "Or still busy at",
    "secondline" : "work?"
  }, {
    "title" : "Mountainbiking",
    "image" : "image3.jpg",
    "firstline" : "Get out and be",
    "secondline" : "active"
  }, {
    "title" : "Mountains Landscape",
    "image" : "image1.jpg",

    "firstline" : "Take a fresh breath of",
    "secondline" : "nature"
  }, {
    "title" : "Italian pizza",
    "image" : "image2.jpg",
    "firstline" : "Enjoy some delicious",
    "secondline" : "food"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#next").click(function(){
    alert("dash is a strategical boy");
    navigate("next");
  });
});
$("#prev").click(function(){
  alert("dash is a strategical boy from prev");
  navigate("back");
});
var currentImg=0;
animating=false;

var navigate = function(direction) {
  if(animating) {
    return;

  }
  if(direction == "next") {
    currentImg++;
    alert("I am inside Next");
    if(currentImg == photos.length + 1) {
      currentImg = 1;
    }
  } else {
    currentImg--;
    alert("I am inside prev");

    if(currentImg === 0) {
      currentImg = photos.length;
    }
  }

  var maincontainer=$("#slider_caption");

  showImage(photos[currentImg - 1],direction);
};
var showImage = function(photoObject,direction,maincontainer){
  alert("I am Also Called");
  animating = true;
  if (direction == "next") {
    if (maincontainer)
      maincontainer.animate({"left":"1080px"},slideshowspeed,linear,function(){
        alert("I am also called");
        $("#slider_caption").css({
          "background-image" : "photoObject.image"
        });
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: No it is not .It is just a part of script :

Comment: @SanketShah Then why did you add the irrelevant part of your script?

Comment: Full script is at js Fiddle pLease help!

Comment: @SanketShah Checking out. Is it okay, if I propose a different working solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368910/jquery-animation-function-is-not-working-in-my-jquery-slider/34368921#34368921

Comment: Actually I am trying to findout why it is not working as already there are  many other solutions here.

Comment: @SanketShah Can you please explain, what you are trying to do, so that I can give you a better solution?

Comment: Orginally i want to manipulate #main_slider .What i want is -On click next main slider should be moved out of display and background image should be changed .After that it should be moved to original place thus acting like a slider:- The code is 
var showimage=function(photoObject,sliderWrapper,mainContainer){
 animating=true;
 mainContainer.animate({"left":"-1080px"},3000,linear,function(){
  $("#main_slider").css({
   "background-image" : "url(images/" + photoObject.image + ")"
  });
     mainContainer.animate({"left":"0px"},3500,linear,function(){
   alert("it is completed");
  });
 });
};